# Where does app get assigned? I keep getting BadArgumentError: app must not be empty

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm attempting to build a simple Google App Engine App using TDD.

$ python functional_tests.py

```
WARNING:root:initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:952) raised BadArgumentError(app must not be empty.)  
WARNING:root:suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1231) raised BadArgumentError(app must not be empty.)  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "functional_tests.py", line 23, in <module>  
    from main import Customer  
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py", line 39, in <module>  
    if not ( Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()):  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1218, in get  
    return self.get_async(**q_options).get_result()  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result  
    self.check_success()  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along  
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1231, in _get_async  
    res = yield self.fetch_async(1, **q_options)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 371, in _help_tasklet_along  
    value = gen.send(val)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 957, in _run_to_list  
    dsquery = self._get_query(conn)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 918, in _get_query  
    group_by=group_by)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 104, in positional_wrapper  
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 1906, in __init__  
    ancestor=ancestor)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 104, in positional_wrapper  
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 1745, in __init__  
    self.__app = datastore_types.ResolveAppId(app).encode('utf-8')  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 229, in ResolveAppId  
    ValidateString(app, 'app', datastore_errors.BadArgumentError)  
  File "/usr/local/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 177, in ValidateString  
    raise exception('%s must not be empty.' % name)  
google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadArgumentError: app must not be empty.
```

This is the code from functional_test.py

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
import unittest  

import sys  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")  
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")  

import dev_appserver  
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2  
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import python_runtime  
from google.appengine.ext import testbed  

from main import Customer  

class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):  

    def setUp(self):  
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
        self.testbed.activate()  
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()  

        # setup the dev_appserver  
        APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']  
        python_runtime._RUNTIME_ARGS = [  
                    sys.executable,  
                    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dev_appserver.__file__),  
                                 '_python_runtime.py')  
        ]  

        options = devappserver2.PARSER.parse_args([  
            '--admin_port', '0',  
            '--port', '9080',  
            '--datastore_path', ':memory:',  
            '--logs_path', ':memory:',  
            '--skip_sdk_update_check',  
            '--',  
        ] + APP_CONFIGS)  
        server = devappserver2.DevelopmentServer()  
        server.start(options)  
        self.server = server  

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)  

    def tearDown(self):  
        self.browser.quit()  
        self.testbed.deactivate()
```

This is the code from main.py:

```
import os  
import urllib  
import logging  

from google.appengine.api import users  
from google.appengine.ext import ndb  

import jinja2  
import webapp2  

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(  
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),  
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],  
    autoescape=True)  

DEFAULT_LEADBOOK_NAME = 'NameCustomer'  

# We set a parent key on the 'Customer' to ensure that they are all in the same  
# entity group. Queries across the single entity group will be consistent.  
# However, the write rate should be limited to ~1/second.  

def leadbook_key(leadbook_name=DEFAULT_LEADBOOK_NAME):  
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a LeadBook entity with leadbook_name."""  
    return ndb.Key('LeadBook', leadbook_name)  

# Client logs in as a User  
# take the User.id and use that to create a child Client  
class Client(ndb.Model):  
    # It seems that I need to figure out how to have the user log in via Google then add the additional info  
    email =  ndb.StringProperty() # I think this would be email address  
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)  
    street1 = ndb.StringProperty()  
    street2 = ndb.StringProperty()  
    city = ndb.StringProperty()  
    zipcode = ndb.IntegerProperty()  
    phone = ndb.StringProperty()  
    signup = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)  

if not ( Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()):  
    logging.info("create Admin")  
    client = Client(  
    email = "bryan@mail.com",  
    name = "Bryan Wheelock",  
    street1 = "555 Main St",  
    street2 = "unit 1",  
    city = "Atlanta",  
    zipcode = 99999,  
    phone = "(888)555-1212"  
    ).put()
```

Comment: Try to add `self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='your_app_id')` just after `self.testbed.activate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the badargumenterror by importing the model into the setup of the unittest.TestCase .

```
class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):  

    def setUp(self):  
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
        self.testbed.activate()  
        #self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='dermalfillersecrets')  
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub()  

        # setup the dev_appserver  
        APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']  
        python_runtime._RUNTIME_ARGS = [  
                    sys.executable,  
                    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dev_appserver.__file__),  
                                 '_python_runtime.py')  
        ]  
        ######## This is the Where I moved the import clause ####
        from main import Customer 
        #########################################################


        options = devappserver2.PARSER.parse_args([  
            '--admin_port', '0',  
            '--port', '9080',  
            '--datastore_path', ':memory:',  
            '--logs_path', ':memory:',  
            '--skip_sdk_update_check',  
            '--',  
        ] + APP_CONFIGS)  
        server = devappserver2.DevelopmentServer()  
        server.start(options)  
        self.server = server  

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()  
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
```

Comment: I'm running into the same error, but from a different type of code. Any idea what the issue was? Not sure how importing a model can fix this.